# Burninate [frontend]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I don't really see what role the [frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) can possibly bring to a question. Couple of issues I have:

- It does not describe any particular technology or framework
- It's completely ambiguous seemingly trying to cover everything from web UI frameworks to command line programs, does beg the question, given this vague description what **isn't** frontend!

> The user-facing part of an application. In a desktop application this would include the windowing framework and the forms the user interacts with; in a command line program it would be the available commands and arguments; and in a web app it would refer to the HTML and JavaScript.

- The wiki has only been edited **once in the 13 years**, so this points at it being legacy
- The list of technologies included in this tag seem endless, [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue), [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap). Though the majority appear to be web based. My personal favourite:

[dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic)[wolfram-mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-mathematica) [frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) [interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interactive)

---

Looking at the [criteria for burination:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
> and is it unambiguous?

**Yes**, It is totally ambiguous

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

**Yes** it is on topic

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**No** not really.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

**No** web technology differs a great deal from command line for example.

Comment: Just as a note: "It doesn't not describe any particular technology or framework" nor do [tag:arrays], [tag:matrox] or [tag:plot], to name but a few. And those are definitely on-topic.

Comment: Meh. From Shog9's "criteria" post (that you linked): *If it looks like pointless busywork, it probably is pointless busywork...* The tag has 11.5k questions.

Comment: The problem with this being ambiguous is that it's *very* often misused. I see it a lot attached to anything JavaScript related even if there is nothing at all to do with "frontend". For example, the question might be how to loop through an array and do something. It might even be tagged with Node.JS which makes the misuse comical. I can't remember seeing the tag used appropriately. Probably because I don't even know what would be appropriate for it.

Comment: I have a question about the inclusion of header files in my C program. Do I tag it [[tag:frontend]] because it comes at the front end of my code?

Comment: I mean, on a cooking site it is vitally important that you tag a pizza as food, or you'd mistake it for a doormat.

Comment: i write front end appilcation and backend applications, depending on custimer needs, so if i have a problem, with the front end lets for example my discussionpoint with microsoft, about Datagridvboew, doesn't work properly when usind a mdi, why would that be a problem, or how should i tag it instead.  **-1** for my part

Comment: Tag it [tag:webforms] @nbk. I also write "backend" and "frontend" applications. Where the technology runs isn't particularly important.

Comment: @Liam i don't mean webfrontend

Comment: The main problem that Shog forgot to mention is that this tag takes the space of more relevant tags. And no, I'm not speaking about the 5 tags limit, I'm talking about that they instead of using useful tags like the language, library or framework they are using, the use [frontend][arrays][loops].

Comment: This is the end of [frontend]...

Comment: #irefusetopun :D

Comment: Hashtagging is a pun in itself though, nowadays :)

Comment: @nbk then tag it [[tag:winforms]]. There is even a [[tag:datagridview]]. I don't see how "frontend" is a useful descriptor for a question over tagging with the concrete technology you use. And if you tag with the actual technology, then what useful information does "frontend" convey?

Comment: @braiam Regarding "taking the space of more relevant tags" it seems [4819 of the 11.5K questions (42%)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1585957/number-of-tags-on-questions-with-a-given-tag?Tag=frontend) use the max 5 tags.

Comment: @DanielWiddis you ignored that I said "I'm not speaking about the 5 tags limit". I don't care if your php question uses 5 tags, as long as it doesn't use php those tags crowded out the relevant one.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't ignore you at all.  In fact I was supporting your comment by pointing out the number of questions which hit the max tag limit and thus potentially crowded out relevant ones.  Analyzing whether any of those 4.8K tags actually did crowd out others is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to concur with the burnination of this tag.

"Frontend" means different things in different contexts.

- Doing a C/C++ application? There's already tags for a lot of those frontends.
- Doing a Java *desktop* application?  Swing exists.
- Doing a Java *full-stack* application on the web?  You could use JSP or Thymeleaf.
- Doing a web app in JavaScript?  Ember or React is your drug of choice.
- Doing a web app in TypeScript?  You've got Angular and Vue to pick from.
- Oh, the less said about CLI applications having graphical frontends, the better. (Just kidding, I actually like those.)

So...someone asking a question about "the frontend" wouldn't be able to stand on its own two feet without some additional information.

Answer (score -3):

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
>
> **Yes** it is on topic

As your question has indicated it has failed at least one of the Burnination criteria, then it should not be burninated.

As the [criteria link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) you included says,

> If you're thinking that these criteria are gonna be pretty tedious to evaluate on a tag with thousands of questions in it, then you're absolutely right

I'm unconvinced you have put forth the effort to evaluate the 11,470 questions beyond some hand-wavey statements that could equally apply to probably half of the tags on SO.

There are far better tags to spend community effort on burninating than this one.

I would support a request to make the tag a synonym of [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) (which has 54K questions and a better tag description/wiki/pointer to the UX site).

Comment: SO painted itself in the wall requiring that tags fails every test. The original criteria, and one that I agree with says that if it fails _any_. Also, this tag topic is undefined. I can post a question about "frontend" that isn't even development.

Comment: It's on topic but very ambiguous. I would argue there is almost always a better tag to use than the generic [tag:frontend]. That said, 11K questions is a lot to sift through and I while agree that it probably shouldn't exist, burnination or disambiguation going to be more effort than it's worth unless it's particularly harmful, e.g. attracting an abundance of low-quality or off-topic questions.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest SE can remove the tag in a single button action.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (and I might be, pre-coffee on a Sunday), that's not a resolution in the burnination process. That sounds more like a "break glass" scenario and sidesteps the closer look applied to questions with the offending tag during the burnination process.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest that wasn't the break glass solution, [that was _the solution_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/262307/revisions), until there weren't enough CM to push the button

Comment: Okay, but the burnination process began roughly six years ago based on the [original answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071) date. On top of that, what happens if a CM nukes a tag, but questions *only* have that tag? We are probably delving too deep into this discussion here but the way I see it, today that would be a break glass scenario where we have a process around curating this content during burnination. I'm willing to discuss this further in SOCVR in the spirit of keeping this discussion on topic.

Comment: *I'm unconvinced you have put forth the effort to evaluate the 11,470 questions beyond some hand-wavey statements* what effort would you expect exactly?

Comment: @liam a representative sample (first page of 100 perhaps) with a percentage breakdown of the impact of the tag (what better tag did it replace? Is it off topic?)  An equivalent analysis for the [user-interface] tag as well. Also an estimate of how long it would take to edit that many posts at the average burnination rate of the last few burns.

Comment: Erm... I have a job and children. Probably not going to spend anything more than 10 minutes on this

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417744/burninate-frontend/417795?noredirect=1#comment907853_417795

Comment: @Liam I don't think SE does one-click tag removal any more.  And if they did, I think you should expand your target.  Personally I think [frontend] should be a synonym for [user-interface] with 54K questions.  And the same reasons you outlined above would apply to [user-interface].

Comment: Meh `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Moving on with my life